# Issue with INFO logs not printed for spring app running on tomcat in Docker

Tags: docker, tomcat

Recently we are facing a weird issue where we are not able to see INFO logs not printed for the spring app deployed using Tomcat on docker container.

When we run same application outside docker we are able to see INFO logs. Also this started happening all of sudden without any major code changes.

Docker file used is

```
FROM tomcat:8.5.37

ADD ./target/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/application.war
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Any help on further troubleshooting directions?

Comment: Where are you trying to find the logs? Can you add the contents of your `/etc/docker/daemon.json` if the file exists on your system?

Comment: What's your docker logging driver and config?  How is your app logging info? Is the app passing this to your container’s STDOUT or STDERR?

Comment: Had issue with application itself. Could not find root cause why it started happening all of sudden, I changed to latest logger implementation in the application which resolved the issue.